# Question about Graf’s and Gegenbauer’s Addition Theorems

Tags: physics, fourier-series, bessel-functions, wave-equation

Anyone can help me?
Using the following figure and from [Graf's addition theorem](https://wikiwaves.org/Graf%27s_Addition_Theorem) we can write:

[image: Graf addition theorem parameter definitions]

How about the values of this expression:

[image: the equation is here]

Thank you.